# NSPredicate as a macro?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I will be adding a series of `NSPredicates` to my model objects, I would like to add these `NSPredicates` to my header as macros, so I could use them like this:

```
NSArray *filteredResults = FILTER_ARRAY_BY_NAME(rawArray, nameString);
```

One of the reasons to wanting to do this is to have the different macros visible in my header and make it easy to change/add or delete predicate macros.

Macro syntax still elude me a bit, but how would this NSPredicate translate to a macro?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentCategoryID == '%@'", categoryID];
return [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope someone can help me out a bit, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? Why not just a normal function, or perhaps a class method, or maybe even a categorical method.

Comment: No it didn't have to be a macro. I have 5-10 predicates I have to implement at first, they will be changed, and more added, as the model evolves and I will be calling them from multiple places inside my model class. A macro would be a good way of keeping them in the header, keep them all similar and quickly add/edit new ones. If my need for predicates turn out to be larger I will probably add a category on my model or implement at set of class methods to group them all - I you have a good way of implementing something like this I am always interested in new/better ways:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
#define FILTER_ARRAY_BY_NAME(rawArray, nameString) [rawArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameString == '%@'", nameString]]
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob:) Apparently I was close.

Comment: Yes it worked. I did however remove the '' single quotation marks around the variable, so it is :"nameString == %@". I have wondered about this earlier because the documentation clearly states they should be there, but I have always omitted them in my predicates to make them work?